# XAMPP Unknown Error Occured after editing php.ini file

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've been using the same XAMPP apache installation for a long time with no issue.

Today I edited the php.ini file in order to try and resolve an issue in my application with file upload limit size and after saving the changes in the php.ini my apache server stopped working. I restered XAMPP and it now says:

Unknown Error Occured in Application

I've tried reinstating the original state of the php.ini file with no success and I've restarted my machine also with no success.

Comment: Can you attach some screenshot of the error, or maybe check your apache logs to see if there are any further details for this error. Maybe add last 10 lines of apache error logs here as well?

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm developing in php with laravel on my localhost using xampp rather than homestead. is there a more suitable stack site I should be asking this question to?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by simply uninstalling and reinstalling xampp.

It seems that editing the php.ini with apache running was the cause of the issue.

Comment: HI When resinstalling di you have to update databases?

Comment: @wilky I did have to restore all db's yes